# "Inactive Wrapper" creating TONS of blank space

Tags: php, html, css, styles, wrapper

I'm in the process of creating a website (a beginner obviously) and for some reason, on one of my pages, the footer section is MUCH longer than it is supposed to be. Its werid because on other pages, it looks fine. I used the exact same code on a new page and the footer is all out of whack. Here's what I get when I inspect the element on Chrome:

```
 <div id="skel-layers-inactiveWrapper" style="height: 100%;">
```

I can't find anything regarding inactive Wrappers or anything of the sorts in any of my css files either. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have you a doctype defined

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Solved the issue for me.

*I know I'm a bit late on this

Answer (score 1):

try to hide the element `<div id="skel-layers-inactiveWrapper">`

The CSS

```
#skel-layers-inactiveWrapper{
    display:none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "100%" to a smaller value, or post more code so we have more to work with :)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, heres some additional code         '<footer id="footer">
<h2 class="major"><span><a href ="/contact.php"> Get in touch</a></span></h2>
<center><ul class="contact">
         <li><a class="icon fa-facebook" href="#"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li><li><a class="icon fa-twitter" href="#"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
<li><a class="icon fa-google-plus" href="#"><span class="label">Google+</span></a></li>
        </ul></center>
<div id="copyright">
<ul class="menu">
<li>&copy; Govpal. All rights reserved 2014</li>
</ul></div></footer>'

Answer (score 0):

Height of 100% refers to the height of the container. The chances are that the instances that work have a surrounding DIV which this one does not and so it is probably taking the height of the entire body (or much larger div) and doubling it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entire code in context. The only tags it is embedded within are  and  tags.

```
<footer id="footer">
<!-- Contact -->
<h2 class="major"><span><a href ="/contact.php"> Get in touch</a></span></h2>
                                                            <center><ul class="contact">
                                <li><a class="icon fa-facebook" href="#"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="icon fa-twitter" href="#"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                                <li><a class="icon fa-google-plus" href="#"><span class="label">Google+</span></a></li>
                            </ul></center>
            <!-- Copyright -->
                <div id="copyright">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li>&copy; Govpal. All rights reserved 2014</li>
                    </ul>
                                    </div>

        </footer>
```